# Check list and edit second list accordingly

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have 3 lists (same shape - about 800 elements), with values being either **1 or 0**. What I want to achieve is a new list that contains the number of **1s in the other 3 lists for that index**.

*To explain further...*

```
# I have these
list1 = [1, 0, 1]
list2 = [1, 1, 1]
list3 = [0, 0, 1]

# I want this

new_list = [2, 1, 3]
```

I got this to work by having a nested for loop (i.e: loop through each list and edit the new_list accordingly). However, I was wondering whether there exists a more efficient (especially on memory and resources) approach.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with numpy - are you in fact using numpy arrays?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry that was in fact my error... approved edit accordingly. I am using lists. (changing numpy arrays to lists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you

```
# I have these
list1 = [1, 0, 1]
list2 = [1, 1, 1]
list3 = [0, 0, 1]

[sum(i) for i in zip(list1, list2, list3)]
```

> [2, 1, 3]

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, `numpy` provides a vectorised approach:

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [1, 0, 1]
list2 = [1, 1, 1]
list3 = [0, 0, 1]

res = np.sum([list1, list2, list3], axis=0).tolist()

# [2, 1, 3]
```